# Can Message Driven Bean read the queue names from a properties file

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

Case: Have and messaging appln will be deployed to JBOSS 6.1.1 server. Have different queue names for different environments. Is there any way to have the queue names and the details read from a config file instead of  Queuenames

- Hard coded in Annotation
- Defined in ejb-jar.xml
- Referring in jboss Standalone.xml

Regards,
Sucheta

Answer (score 0):

You can put `properties` file in the root of your server. Access it within `FileInputStream` and set it in your `MDB` class.
make a singleton class and read the properties from this class:

```
public class EnvironmentProperties {

    private static final EnvironmentProperties INSTANCE = new EnvironmentProperties();

    private Properties props = null;
    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(EnvironmentProperties.class);

    private EnvironmentProperties() {
        loadProperties();
    }

    public static EnvironmentProperties getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public String getJmsName() {
        return props.getProperty("jms.name");
    }

    public String getJmsQueue() {
        return props.getProperty("jms.queue");
    }

    private Object readResolve() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private Properties loadProperties() {
        props = new Properties();
        try {
            String filePath = new File("./config.properties").getCanonicalPath();
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);           
            props.load(fis);
            fis.close();            
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(),  e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(),  e);
        }
        return props;
    }

}
```

get access to jms/queue name : `EnvironmentProperties.getInstance().getJmsName();`

Make sure the `properties` file existed on all your servers